# Call a APi in Xamarin Combobox

Tags: xamarin.forms

this is mine model class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace EssentialUIKit.Models
{
    public partial class InspectionModel
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }
        public string EmpId { get; set; }
        public string Process { get; set; }
         
    }
}
```

this is another class where I am deserializing and calling api

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EssentialUIKit.Models
{
    public class InspectionManager
    {
        const string Url = "http://localhost:8085/api/QMSInspection/GetProcess/";

        public async Task<IEnumerable<InspectionModel>> GetProcess()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            string result = await client.GetStringAsync(Url);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<InspectionModel>>(result);
        }
    }
}
```

this is
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC8LY.png)

of code where I am calling it and it is giving an error in ProcessPicker.datasource:
Error is : cannot convert method group "getprocess" into non-delegate type 'IEnumerable' Object.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: GetProcess is a method, so you must use () when calling it

Comment: no it didn't work that way too !

Comment: it gives the exact same error message?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qG1Xl892VoZYEHOebrXGZYq4UNanW5wK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: as I already told you, please do NOT post code or errors as images!  This is against the site rules

Comment: you are using trying to call an async method without await, and from a constructor

Comment: Oh ok sorry I delete that pic link ! await not working so how can I do that ! Can you please tell !

Comment: I called that method but now it is giving me this error: Unhandled Exception:

System.Net.WebException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8085) after 120000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) occurred

Comment: What is your `ProcessPicker`? Have you check your url? I tested on the url with include the json. It did not thrown the error.

Comment: My API is working fine now ! But I am not able to get data inside datasource of combobox.How to get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Picker to do the things like combobox, you could try the ways below. Since the url you provided seems created by yourself, i use the a url include json for reference.

url:

```
https://b0f54da1-5488-4321-9583-d89d4cf66728.mock.pstmn.io/dynamic
```

Json class:

```
  public class Model
{
    public Guid GuidId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

xaml:

```
  <StackLayout>
    <!--  Place new controls here  -->
    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
    <Picker x:Name="ProcessPicker" />
</StackLayout>
```

**Solution1:**

An easy way to use `Flurl.Http` get the json list from the url and binding one of the property to picker itemsource. There is no need for the matched class for json data. In Xamarin.forms, i use ItemSource for Picker.

```
 async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IList<dynamic> list = await "https://b0f54da1-5488-4321-9583-d89d4cf66728.mock.pstmn.io/dynamic".GetJsonListAsync();
        var modelList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            modelList.Add(item.Name);
        }
        ProcessPicker.ItemsSource = modelList;

    }
```

**Solution2:**

InspectionManager.cs:

```
 public class InspectionManager
{
    const string Url = "https://b0f54da1-5488-4321-9583-d89d4cf66728.mock.pstmn.io/dynamic"; //"http://www.pizzaboy.de/app/pizzaboy.json";//"http://localhost:8085/api/QMSInspection/GetProcess/";

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Model>> GetProcess()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string result = await client.GetStringAsync(Url);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Model>>(result);
    }
}
```

MainPage:

```
readonly InspectionManager manager = new InspectionManager();

    public IEnumerable<Model> s { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
    }

    async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s = await manager.GetProcess();
      
        var modelList = new List<string>();
        
        foreach (var item in s)
        {
            modelList.Add(item.Name);
        }

        ProcessPicker.ItemsSource = modelList;
    }
```